# How to set up computer (ubuntu) on Github by using SSH through proxy?

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh

When I copy/paste `ssh -T git@github.com` or even `ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com` it does not work. . . I got this message `ssh: connect to host ssh.github.com: Connection timed out.`

I tried differents solutions to solve this but none worked... Someone knows how to resolve this through proxy connection ? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: What proxy do you use? Does it even support SSH?

Comment: It's a HTTP PROXY and I think it does not support ssh...

Comment: Then use git over http(s) or a vpn.

Comment: I tried but how can I then test my connection through the default command `ssh -T git@github.com` ?

Comment: If you use http(s), you cannot test it using the `ssh -T git@github.com` command. If you use a vpn you can do this.